# Showing that a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable, and calculate two iterated integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Given is the function on $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x ≥ 0 \text{ and } x ≤ y < x+1 \\ -1 & \text{ if } x ≥ 0 \text{ and } x+1 ≤ y < x+2 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I now first want to justify why $f$ is (Borel-)measurable. Next, I want to calculate the two integrals:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f(x, y) dx \right) dy \text{ and } \int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f(x, y) dy \right) dx$$

Regarding Borel-measurable: intuitively, I think $f$ sends everything to $0$, except for the two small "stripes" within $\mathbb{R}^2$ that start at the origin and go infinitely in one direction.

Formally, since it's sufficient to show that $f^{-1}(\{1\}), f^{-1}(\{-1\}), f^{-1}(\{0\})$ are measurable sets (since these are the only values that $f$ takes), we can write:

$$f(\{1\}) = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x ≥ 0, x ≤ y < x+1\} = \underbrace{\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x ≥ 0, x ≤ y ≤ x+1\}}_{\text{closed, hence measurable}} \backslash \underbrace{\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x ≥ 0, x = y\}}_{\text{closed, hence measurable}} $$

and therefore, $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is measurable. $f^{-1}(\{-1\})$ goes analogous, and $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash (f^{-1}(\{1\}) \cup f^{-1}(\{-1\}))$ is therefore measurable too.

I don't really know how to approach these two iterated integrals. If I want to first integrate over $x$ and then over $y$, how do I actually do that with such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument to show that $f$ is Borel-measurable is fine (except that you wanted to write $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x ≥ 0, x+1 = y\}$).

In order to compute $\int_\mathbb{R} ( \int_\mathbb{R} f(x, y) dx ) dy$, let $y \in \mathbb R$ fixed and then we first compute $$I_y = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x, y) dx.$$

- If $y < 0$, then $f(x,y) = 0$ for every real number $x$, so that $I_y=0$
- If $0 \le y < 1$, then $f(x,y)=1$ if $0 \le x \le y$, and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Therefore, $I_y = \int_0^y 1 dx = y$.
- If $1<y <2$, then $f(x,y)=-1$ if $0 \le x \le y-1$, $f(x,y)=1$ if $y-1<x<y$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Therefore, $I_y = \int_{0}^{y-1} -1 + \int_{y-1}^{y} 1  = 1-y+1=2-y$.
- If $y>2$, then $f(x,y)=-1$ if $y-2 \le x \le y-1$, $f(x,y)=1$ if $y-1<x<y$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Therefore, $I_y = \int_{y-2}^{y-1} -1 + \int_{y-1}^{y} 1  = 0$.

Then you just have to see what is $\int_\mathbb{R} I_y dy$ (which exists since $y \mapsto I_y$ is Borel-measurable).

Comment: Thanks. So since $y \mapsto I_y = y $ for $ y \in [0, 1)$, and $= 2-y$ for $y \in [1, 2)$, and $0$ everywhere else, do I assume right that $\int_\mathbb{R} I_y dy = 1$? And does the other iterated integral where $y$ is in the inner integral and $x$ in the outer one work analogous? (I think I'll attempt to solve the second integral on the same way, and see where it leads.)

Comment: You're right, the first integral is $1$. The second one works analogous. This will lead to a different result. So, you are dealing with a counterexample to [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem).